# Module for Saving Drupal node page without "closing"

Tags: drupal, forms

Is there a Drupal module out there that allows users to save the changes to a node creation form while still keeping the form in the edit mode?

If you preview, the node isn't saved, if you save the editing form is closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Save & Edit](http://drupal.org/project/save_edit)

> The module simply adds a button titled "Save & Edit" on node types selected in the admin section. Using this extra button when saving a node will simply redirect back to the edit form rather than returning to the node page, or the /admin/content/node page.